# How to connect pc speaker to 2 channel dvd player

Tags: audio, speakers, music

I am having [Creative Inspire M2600](http://tech.firstpost.com/product/speakers/inspire-m2600-specification-92262.html) pc speaker. I need to connect it to a dvd player which having output of 40w-40w and not having a 3.5 mm out.
Can i connect the dvd output to a 3.5 mm female jack and plug the pc speaker's 3.5mm male to that female port. Is it possible? If not, please let me know how can it possible.

Comment: What DVD player only has  amplified speaker outputs. Picture and model number

Comment: Its a local brand dvd player

Comment: If the DVD player has a headphone jack, you could connect the Creative speaker system to that.

Comment: No headphone jacks.  Only LR out

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't connect them directly. Outputs designed to drive 40W into a pair of speakers can exceed 20V or so and damage the line level input of your M2600, which expects a signal of around 1V or so. In addition, both speaker terminals may be floating with respect to ground and the M2600 will expect one of them to be at ground, so connecting directly may damage the outputs of your DVD player.

But there is a solution. This used to be a very common issue in car audio systems where people wanted to add amplifiers but only had speaker outputs to connect them to (many head units nowadays have pre-amp outputs for this). You can use a speaker to line level converter such as this one:

[image]

[Here's the link to this one](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/in-phase-speaker-to-rca-converter-adjustable-output-gain-r52mc) but I'm sure eBay is full of alternatives, just search for speaker to line level converter. For this one you would need an adaptor cable to connect two PCA phono connectors to a stereo 3.5" jack, but other versions may have the correct connector already.

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Does it need dc power supply? Is it have 3.5 mm output?

Comment: The one in the link does need power, according to the link anything from 9 to 16V DC. I'm guessing it's because it has adjustable gain, but it should be possible to do the same job with a passive device that won't need power. I'm not suggesting this is the one you should use, it's just an example of the type of device and no, it doesn't have 3.5mm output so you'd need an adaptor cable.

Comment: I fitted such a device which does not need extra power. Its working now. But getting engine noise. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It appears, from what I can see on the Creative website, that the Inspire M2600 system is not a bare speaker, but includes amplifiers - since it is described as a "pc speaker", it will accept the line level audio output from a computer, iPad, or similar device.  You should not connect it directly to the 40 Watt speaker output of your DVD player.